# Difference between $\sum_i\frac{a_i}{b_i}$ and $\frac{\sum_i a_i}{\sum_i b_i}$

Tags: real-analysis

Take ratio $\frac{a}{b}$ such that $a>0$, $b>0$. The $a$ can be some measurement and $b$ reference, for example. Having more of such measurements, arithmetic mean of these ratios is

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\frac{a_i}{b_i}$$

Another expression that intuitively feels like average is

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^N a_i}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^N b_i}$$

Am I just confused and the second formula has no practical significance, or it relates to the first one in some way? They are not the same, but is it possible they converge to the same value for $N\to\infty$?

The ratio $\frac{a_i}{b_i}$ for represents savings. Take $a_i$ algorithm run time after optimization and $b_i$ algorithm run time before optimization, where $b_i\geq a_i$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i \to \infty$, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}b_i \to \infty$ and $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}b_i} \in [0,1]$$

The motivation is as follows: from standpoint where arithmetic mean cannot be used directly I hope to approximate it using the second formula. It seems to give similar results in practice, but I need formal validation why this can be used instead (if it can, of course).

Comment: What happens to the second formula if you replace $a_i/b_i$ by $2a_i/2b_i$ for some fixed $i$? You would like there to be no change if you are only interested in the value of $a_i/b_i$. The second expression is not a well-defined function of the ratios $a_i/b_i$.

Comment: I may be looking at this wrong, but I'm getting a [Farey-addition](http://www.math.mun.ca/~sergey/Winter06/CA/Asst1/asst3sup.pdf) feeling about the second formula

Comment: @EricThoma If you assume that $\sum a_i$ and $\sum b_i$ diverge, then changing a single datum will make no difference in the limit $N\to\infty$. Your objection is probably still sound in principle, but it will take some more work to make it stick.

Comment: Whoa. Not even remotely. If a student asked what's the difference between $\frac 13 + frac 25 = \frac {11}{15} $ and $\frac {1+2}{3+5}=\frac 38$ and are they somehow related, what would you say? Even if (especially if) the first were divided in 1/2 could you say that made any sense?

Comment: Yes they are not the same, for example with $\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ with $b\neq 0$, $d\neq 0$, $b\neq -d$ it would equal arithmetic mean of $\{\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}\}$ only if $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ or when $b=d$. The question was, however, whether the two formulas can converge to the same value for infinite length sequence.

Comment: @user330617 Should I give an example where both formulas are the same?

Comment: I already gave such example in preceding comment. Thank you for your answer. What about the case when individual sums of $a_i$, $b_i$ will not converge, but their fraction will. Take $a\in[0,1]$, $b\in[0,1]$ and $a<b$. Then the ratio will always be in $[0,1]$. Will this under any condition or in some special case converge to arithmetic mean?

Comment: Here I made some edits to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this could help..

If you write out the sums you will get.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_i}{b_i}=\frac{a_1}{b_1}+\frac{a_2}{b_2}+\frac{a_3}{b_3}+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{b_n}$$

And
 $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i}=\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n}{b_1+b_2+b_3+\cdots+b_n}$$

As you can see you have to find sequences where..

$$\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n}{b_1+b_2+b_3+\cdots+b_n}=\frac{a_1}{b_1}+\frac{a_2}{b_2}+\frac{a_3}{b_3}+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{b_n}$$

Now suppose $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i$ converge. That does not mean $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{a_i}{b_i}$ will converge. Just substitute $a_i={\frac{1}{2}}^i$ and $b_i=\frac{1}{3}^{i}$. You'll find that

$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{2^i}}{\frac{1}{3^i}}\neq\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^i}}$.
Rarely would converging sequences in the form of  be the same. So I do not see much potential with comparing $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_i}{b_i}$ with $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i}$.

---

EDIT:
If both $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_i$ diverges but the sum of $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{b_i}$ converges then in most cases $\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i}{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_i}$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{b_i}$ will not have the same value. While $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{b_i}$ will mostly converge to a number greater than zero , $\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i}{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_i}$ will mostly converge to zero(if $\lim_{i\to\infty}\frac{a_i}{b_i}=0$) or $\infty$ ($\lim_{i\to\infty}\frac{a_i}{b_i}=\infty$).

However if your using the aritmetic mean, where $$\lim_{i\to\infty}\frac{a_i}{b_i}=c$$ then yes. $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{a_i}{b_i}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n {a_i}}{\sum_{i=0}^{n}b_i}$$

This is simple to prove because if $\lim_{i\to\infty} \frac{a_i}{b_i}=c$ then we get $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}c$ with partial sum formula as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}(cn)=c$. As for $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n}{a_i}}{\sum_{i=0}^n b_i}$ we should treat this as the limit of a function divided by another function. If $\lim_{i\to\infty}\frac{a_i}{b_i}=c$ then the poportion is the use $\lim_{i\to\infty}a_i=c\lim_{i\to\infty}(b_i)$ and thus $\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i}{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_i}=\frac{c\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(b_i)}{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_i}=c$

In this case you can use this identity when $a_i$ and $b_i$ nearly the same or have their limit ratio approach zero. Identities or theorems should make mathematical problems simple. At best, sum indentities on both sides of the equation apply to broad types of functions, not just specfic instances. This is similar to comparing $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ to $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{2^x}$. They both converge to the same limit but comparing them both will not make solving either easier

Comment: Could you elaborate on the proof? I am not sure I follow

Comment: Maybe I am looking at this wrong, but it was not assumed that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{b_i}$ is in itself convergent - it was that $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{b_i}$ is the one that should converge to $L$. Also I don't think the right side need to converge to 0, even $b_i$ grows faster. Take for example $a_i = 0.5b_i$. This satisfies the conditions and converges to $0.5$.

Comment: @student The Op could have meant $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{b_i}$ though his comment below the post he never directly mentioned the arithmetic mean.   I will fix everything else.

Comment: last paragraph of the question states that he hopes to approximate arithmetic mean with the second formula. So you go to it the right way by trying to show equality between the limits. But they won't necessarily go to zero.

Comment: It was not assumed that $\lim_{i\to\infty}\frac{a_i}{b_i}=c$ as $a_i$, $b_i$ can take any values, the sums are suppose to converge to same value as arithmetic mean. I ran simple simulation just to verify the idea, it seems we are onto something.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_i$ is the number of miles traveled during the $i$th leg of a journey and $b_i$ is the number of hours that leg took, then $\displaystyle \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N b_i}$ is the average speed in miles per hour.

Comment: How does this relate to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{a_i}{b_i}$? You should answer everything the OP says.

Comment: @Arbuja : I'm surprised that someone thinks I should make a rule of answering everything the poster said.  I am far from convinced of that, to say the least. $\qquad$

Comment: I apologize if I sounded offensive. I am not forcing you, it was just a suggestion.

Comment: @Arbuja : I didn't find it offensive, but it seemed weird.